# Remove background image and redraw lines in black

Tags: image-processing, syntax, image, computational-geometry, image3d

I do not know if the title is correct.

The image that I upload has liked me a lot because of the characteristic that no matter the angle it seems that it is looking at you, you could indicate me how to make Mathematica take this image and draw me an equivalent.
Beforehand thank you very much.

[image]

EDIT 2
looking post, I have dealt with this but it does not turn out

```
 i1 = Import@"http://img.fenixzone.net/i/I7VxTPi.png"
 ColorReplace[i1, RGBColor@PixelValue[i1, {2, 2}], .02]
 data = ImageData[i1];
 Image[data /. {x_, y_, z_} /; 
 EuclideanDistance[{x, y, z}, data[[2, 2]]] < .3 -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

Comment: I think you'd have to tell Mathematica to invert the pixels and take the background out of the image

Comment: Maybe you could start from here? Binarize[ColorNegate[i1], 0.2]

Comment: thanks you helped me a lot with that, it was simpler than I thought